error 1503 - A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function
in my laravel application, I'm trying to make a dynamic command to copy the table and add created_year so I can do MySQL Partition

I copy that full table

I add the column created_year

I remove the old primary keys and a new one with created_year

I try to PARTITION the table but I got an error



Error adding year partitioning: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1503 A
UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning
function (prefixed columns are not considered). (Connection: mysql, SQL:

My Code here
            // Copying the old table
            DB::statement("
                CREATE TABLE `$newTableName` LIKE `$tableName`
            ");

            // Adding the created_year Column for Partitioning
            DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `$newTableName` ADD COLUMN created_year INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (YEAR(created_at)) STORED");


    // Get primary key information for the existing table
            $databaseName = DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
            $primaryKeyInfo = DB::connection()->select("
                SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
                WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$databaseName'
                AND TABLE_NAME = '$tableName'
                AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PRIMARY'
            ");

            $primaryKeys = [];
            foreach ($primaryKeyInfo as $info) {
                $primaryKeys[] = $info->COLUMN_NAME;
            }

            DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `$newTableName` DROP PRIMARY KEY");

            $primaryKeys[] = 'created_year';
            $newPrimaryKey = implode(',', $primaryKeys);

            DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `$newTableName` ADD PRIMARY KEY ($newPrimaryKey)");


  // Add partitioning by created_year
            DB::statement("
                ALTER TABLE `$newTableName`
                PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(created_year) (
                    PARTITION p2020 VALUES LESS THAN (2021),
                    PARTITION p2021 VALUES LESS THAN (2022),
                    PARTITION p2022 VALUES LESS THAN (2023),
                    PARTITION p2023 VALUES LESS THAN (2024),
                    PARTITION p2024 VALUES LESS THAN (2025),
                    PARTITION p2025 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
                )
            ");

#error

Error adding year partitioning: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1503 A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function (prefixed columns are not considered). (Connection: mysql, SQL:



Have you read this manual page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html

@BillKarwin no i did not i tried with creating table it worked fine but here no what do you suggest

You can't partition the table unless the partition column is part of the primary key (or other unique key). Read the page I linked to. You may not be able to partition this table.

Very MySQL specific problem, so I removed the (general) ANIS/ISO  tag.
